# Android only allow entry through one side of rectangle

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

I am creating a game where the user can move certain objects into others (these are rectangles), however I only want to be able to enter the rectangles through one side, and it will be blocked by the rest.

I have no idea how to go about doing this, I have googled and found nothing that will help me understand what I need to do. Also, how would I go about doing this if the rectangle was at an angle, say 45 degree slope?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Tom, if you are new to Game world you need to search more about game engine for android. 
Actually you need to search more about collision detection in android.

for more help try to read more about this game engine : 
http://www.andengine.org/

there are lots of engines but you need to learn them.

Regards,

Comment: Ah okay, thankyou very much! I've used engines outside of Android, but I didn't know about any Android engines. This is very helpful!

Comment: you cann se more engines here : http://ntt.cc/2011/05/08/8-open-source-android-game-engines.html

Comment: @TomRichardson if this is the right answer for you , click on the left mark to sign this as a valid answer